# VHDL synchronization between different blocks

Tags: synchronization, vhdl

I have tried really hard to search solutions on internet. But I failed thats why I put it here.

I am trying to design a I2C block in FPGA. Basically it receives DATA, MODE information from other blocks. After receiving, I2C will export or read data from its environment devices.

My question is, when I2C communicating with other blocks inside FPGA, how could I2C synchronize with other blocks? I mean how could I2C know if the DATA and MODE received from other blocks is from previous? Or the most updated?

My current idea is to use a pulse generated from other blocks to inform I2C that "new DATA" is coming. Could I know if there is any other ways? What are the differences between these methods?

Thank you very much.

Best regards

Comment: I would probably design a **state machine** to control the interactions between the I2C core and other blocks. You will easily find information on these on internet.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to read UM10204  [I2C-Bus Specification and User Manual](http://www.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/UM10204.pdf) (PDF, 1.4 MB) you might find I<sup>2</sup>C to be more complex than you might expect but well defined.

A reference design in VHDL might come in handy.  Try Frank Buss's  [I2C Slave with PCA9555 example implementation](http://www.frank-buss.de/vhdl/i2c_slave-0.4.zip) (ZIP, 829KB).  The  [PCA9555](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/PCA9555.pdf) (Data Sheet, PDF 529KB) shows read and write pulses to the two 8 bit port devices from the I<sup>2</sup>C interface.   An Interrupt is used to signal an input port event to cause a master to read the device.  I've used PCA9555 family devices in this manner for SONET Alarm stuff.

Your 'pulse generated from other blocks to inform' sounds compatible.  An alternative might be to have either two I<sup>2</sup>C buses or otherwise both master and slave devices both on one or more design blocks.  Lattice Semiconductor has a reference master design  (See [I2C (Inter-Integrated Circuit) Bus Master Controller](http://www.latticesemi.com/products/intellectualproperty/referencedesigns/i2cbusmastercontroller.cfm), the ZIP file  download 494KB, both VHDL and Verilog, licensed for Lattice implementation only) that might be used to teach your own master design implementation, also useful for traffic generators for verification.

Answer (score 0):

> I mean how could I2C know if the DATA and MODE received from other blocks is from previous? Or the most updated?

To (nearly) all signals in my design there is an extra signal called enable e.g.:
data & data_en

So data_en = '1' indicate a new value on data.

This makes design life easy. You can just wait in state machines or calculation pipelines for the next enable and start the processing in the right clock cycle. If your result is ready just set the associacated result_en to '1' and the next block can start working.